# running java code via shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I have a shell script :

`#!/bin/sh`

`java -cp ".:./lib/*"com.test.class_name`

Am a newbie to shell scripting.

Not able to understand what exactly "java -cp" is doing.

Answer (score 0):

cp stands for classpath, this is an option of running JAVA, nothing to do with shell

If you have additional JAR files needed for your java code, you normally use `-cp` or `-classpath` to include the JAR files when running your code

> class search path of directories and zip/jar files